# HuggingFace hate detection model

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers

I am a beginner in NLP and have undertaken a challenge.

I am trying to train and evaluate a hate detection model using the [HuggingFace Transformers library](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) and this [dataset](https://github.com/t-davidson/hate-speech-and-offensive-language/tree/master/data). Model performance is secondary, just trying to get it going. I have preprocessed the data and tokenised it as shown below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import RandomState
import re
import preprocessor as p
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

# Loading raw data
original_data = pd.read_csv('../data/data.csv')

# Make a random test and train split
rng = RandomState()
train = original_data.sample(frac=0.7, random_state=rng)
test = original_data.loc[~df.index.isin(train.index)]

# Preprocessing: remove special characters using RegEx
REPLACE_NO_SPACE = re.compile("(\.)|(\;)|(\:)|(\!)|(\')|(\?)|(\,)|(\")|(\|)|(\()|(\))|(\[)|(\])|(\%)|(\$)|(\>)|(\<)|(\{)|(\})")
REPLACE_WITH_SPACE = re.compile("(<br\s/><br\s/?)|(-)|(/)|(:).")

# Custom function to clean the datasets
def clean_tweets(df):
  tempArr = []
  for line in df:
    # send to tweet_processor
    tmpL = p.clean(line)
    # remove puctuation
    tmpL = REPLACE_NO_SPACE.sub("", tmpL.lower()) # convert all tweets to lower cases
    tmpL = REPLACE_WITH_SPACE.sub(" ", tmpL)
    tempArr.append(tmpL)
  return tempArr

# clean training data
train_tweet = clean_tweets(train["tweet"])
train_tweet = pd.DataFrame(train_tweet)
# append cleaned tweets to the testing data
train["clean_tweet"] = train_tweet

# clean the test data 
test_tweet = clean_tweets(test["tweet"])
test_tweet = pd.DataFrame(test_tweet)
# append cleaned tweets to the training data
test["clean_tweet"] = test_tweet

# Tokenisation so the inputs are ready for the model
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("bert-base-cased")
```

The above code generates a table for the test data as:
[image]

As I understand, the next part should be the model training part and extracting the % of hate tweets. Any suggestions on implementation?

Comment: The next steps would be **creating torch dataset from data**, **creating new instance of `trainer` class**, **performing training** and **evaluation**. You can get inspiration from the [script](https://github.com/meti-94/TextClassification/blob/main/BERT%20Classification.ipynb) I wrote earlier in the simplest way and ask if you have any ambiguity :)

Comment: Why do you lower case your test when you intend to use a cased model? There is also no need to remove punctuation since your model was trained with punctuation. Why do you lowercase your text with a regex?